# Render HTML on headless server to produce screenshots

Tags: html, image-processing

I would like to create screenshots of web pages from a given URL. While it's possible to use tools like Selenium RC, that requires a graphical environment. I am running a headless Gentoo server.

This will be part of a tool chain that works like:

- Fetch URL
- Render HTML
- Export render as image file
- Store image file

Comment: I'm pretty sure that having no monitor attached does not actually prevent you from running an X instance.

Comment: That's a good point actually. You should consider adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an application with framebuffer X-Server like [xvfb](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) -  one simple approach is a Qt based app to render the page in a webkit widget and save as an image. Here's a [blog post outlining how this can be done with Python](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/).

Here's a quick command line tool I've used with Qt. It's a while since I used it but it should still work!

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QSize>

QWebView *view;
QString outfile;

void QWebView::loadFinished(bool ok)
{
        QTextStream out(stdout);
        if (!ok) {
                out << "Page loading failed\n";
                return;
        }
        view->page()->setViewportSize(view->page()->currentFrame()->contentsSize());
        QImage *img = new QImage(view->page()->viewportSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        QPainter *paint = new QPainter(img);
        view->page()->currentFrame()->render(paint);
        paint->end();
        if(!img->save(outfile, "png"))
                out << "Save failure\n";
        QApplication::quit();
        return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QTextStream out(stdout);
        if(argc < 3) {
                out << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " <url> <outfile>\n";
                return -1;
        }
        outfile = argv[2];
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        view = new QWebView();
        view->load(QUrl(argv[1]));

        return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the requirement for QtGUI and QtWebKit requires a full blown X itself. So even without an UI the full X-Server has to be installed. But I guess this can't be avoided.

Comment: Maybe to build it but not to deploy it - typical Ubuntu or Debian box will need xserver-common and a few other packages.